# Selectively training a branch of multi-output model

Tags: python, keras

so I have a keras model with over 10 outputs, and I want to be able to train each output individually. All the other solutions I've seen say to make multiple models, but that makes it so then I have 10+ models I need to save and loading becomes a bit tricky then as well. I've have tried doing that but it seems very inefficient with the number of outputs I'm using so any other ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We need more details here. Can you describe your model architecture and why you need 10 outputs which are trained at different times? Keras makes it very easy to share layers across modules, so there's most likely a convenient way.

Comment: keras.backend has stop_gradient function which can be used for this task. 
Make sure you don't let gradiens flow through shared layer.
To train your shared layers you'll have to train the whole thing with your multiple outputs.
If there are no shared layers I recommend doing seperate layers.